# Is there any screen with resolution of 3440x1080 that is supported by a mid 2012 13" MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have a mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro with an integrated Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU and Thunderbolt / DisplayPort v 1.2 ports.

Can I connect a screen with 3440x1080 resolution? If not, is there anyway to connect two monitors on extended mode?

Comment: @Tetsujin You were right, I've found what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel HD Graphics 4000 supports resolution up to 1920×1200 through HDMI and 2560×1600 through DisplayPort.

Your Mac technically can only support it's own internal display and one external display.

I say technically, since people are creative and here is an example of 3 external monitors.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8gE-ckBwjE